# Adding a python script to my wpf application. Not Embedded

Tags: c#, wpf, resources

I am trying to add a python script to my wpf application. This script is executed in the application via a new process. However I want to be able to update the script without updating the wpf program.

I currently trying something like this, but changes made to the script are not executed.

```
    var script = Resources.parser; 

    var path = Path.Combine(root, "parser.py");

    using (var fw = new StreamWriter(path))
    {
        fw.Write(script);
    }

    ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
    startInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
    startInfo.Arguments = "C:/Anaconda3/python.exe"; 
    DianaLive.p = Process.Start("C:/Anaconda3/python", $"{path} {root} {root}\\{title}.out");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer my own question:

I think it is not the most fancy solution, but I used the path of the assembly to find the resources directory.

```
 var dir = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location);
    var path = Path.Combine(dir, "Resources", "parser.py");

    string script;
    using (var sr = new StreamReader(path))
    {
        script = sr.ReadToEnd();
    }
    path = Path.Combine(root, "parser.pyw");

    using (var fw = new StreamWriter(path))
    {
        fw.Write(script);
    }
```